# How do I fix the make error when I install Ruby 1.9.3 on OSX Lion via RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have been trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 on OSX Lion but keep running into a make error

> Kerrie-Yees-MacBook-Pro:~ kerrieyee$ rvm install 1.9.3
>   Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/kerrieyee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
>
> ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching
>
> ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/kerrieyee/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
>
> ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring
>
> ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling
>
> Error running 'make ', please read /Users/kerrieyee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
>   There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

I have installed git 1.7.7.5, osx-gcc4.2, homebrew 0.9, and XCode 4.3 with command line Tools.  I have tried installing the readline but still get the make error.  I am also very new to ruby and don't know much about terminal so if more information is necessary, please also write the terminal command needed to get the information.  Thank you!

As Per the suggestions, I have opened make.log file

the part that looks like the error portion reads

`readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
    readline.c:1499: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    readline.c:1499: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    readline.c:1499: error: for each function it appears in.)
    make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
    make: *** [build-ext] Error 2`

Noticing that the error had something to do with the readline, I looked up other questions about readline and followed RVM Instructions.

I typed in `rvm pkg install readline` and `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr`

There is still the error:

`Error running 'make ', please read /Users/kerrieyee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.`

and the make.log file reads:

`ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is     not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Error 2
    make: *** [build-ext] Error 2`

Also I ran brew doctor:

> Kerrie-Yees-MacBook-Pro:~ kerrieyee$ brew doctor
>
> Error: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected dylibs:
>      /usr/local/lib/libexslt.0.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libexslt.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libhistory.6.0.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libhistory.6.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libhistory.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libreadline.6.0.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libreadline.6.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libreadline.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libruby.1.8.7.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libruby.1.8.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libruby.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libxml2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libxslt.1.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libxslt.dylib
>
> Error: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected .la files:
>      /usr/local/lib/libexslt.la    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la    /usr/local/lib/libxml2.la    /usr/local/lib/libxslt.la
>
> Error: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected .pc files:
>      /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libexslt.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libxslt.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
>
> Error: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected static libraries:
>      /usr/local/lib/libexslt.a    /usr/local/lib/libhistory.a    /usr/local/lib/libreadline.a    /usr/local/lib/libruby-static.a    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a    /usr/local/lib/libxml2.a    /usr/local/lib/libxslt.a

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion in the error message?

Comment: Show us the full `rvm install` trace please.

Comment: You'll have to include the first few lines in the `make.log` file that look like an error..

Comment: Do brew doctor. It might help. Also you could try rbenv instead of rvm, I feel it's easier to install

Comment: @sarnold When I try to open the make.log file it says permission denied and when I try it sudo, I get `sudo: /Users/kerrieyee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log: command not found`

Comment: @user1446761 the file is not executable, so you have to use something like `open '/Users/kerrieyee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log'` to open the file with the default application (probably console)

Comment: You may need to install the `libreadline` _devel_ packages. I'm not sure what the convention is on OS X systems, but your `‘username_completion_function’ undeclared` error message probably means the `libreadline` headers are missing.

Comment: @sarnold So I have already done '$ rvm pkg install readline'....and I am not sure what libreadline is or how to install it? I would really appreciate your help with this...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this was resolve by me running the following:

> brew update
>
> brew tap homebrew/dupes
>
> brew install apple-gcc42
>
> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Comment: Even though all messages from running this seemed to indicate that nothing was done to the system, once I ran the above then re-ran `rvm install ruby-1.9.3` the install succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure that this will solve your specific problem, but this tutorial I wrote has helped a lot of people: http://moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: sorry this doesn't work for me...maybe if I did a clean reinstall?

Comment: While your article may in fact answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Stack Overflow is only as useful as its questions and answers, and if your blog host goes down or your URLs get moved around, this answer becomes useless. Thanks!